# WSO2 ELB Cluster members registered

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, hazelcast, wso2

i'm using WSO2 ELB 210 and WSO2 ESB 481 to make a cluster. All the configuration is made following the official documentation guide and it works fine.

Now i need to write a client able to  dynamically list the ESB cluster members in order to monitor the situation inside my cluster.

I tried to write an hazelcast client but i m not able to connect to the cluster at all.

What kind of road should i have to follow? Are there some API or services i can use?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful to someone else in future:

The WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer has been discontinued according to July 1st 2015.

Thanks
Shadsha